# In Flutter firebase_ui_auth package how to access to register or login screen's textfields inputs in SignInScreen when using Email/password provider

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, oauth, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter firebase_ui_auth package, and I have successfully implemented the SIgnInScreen flow however I have a very simple question that how can I get access/control over user inputs inside textfields of register/login view of Email/password auth provider of firebase. As I want to get those values like email password so that I can send it to my backend server as well.

I tried to investigate the package but nothing so far worked.